# JNI - compile dll as 64 bit

Tags: dll, java-native-interface, x86, 64-bit, 32-bit

I compile my `.dll` with the following command: `gcc -mno-cygwin -I"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/include" -I"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/include/win32" -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o CalculatorFunctions.dll CalcFunc.c` 
I use GlassFish for Eclipse. The whole system is a CORBA client-server. When I start the server from Eclipse - it's fine. But when I try to run the server from the CMD (because I want to set a port and host address for the server) it gives me: `Exception: ... .dll: Can't load AI 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform`

I searched through other topics and saw that I should try with changing my JDK to 32 bit - didn't work again. 
So the other solution I read about is to compile the .DLL as 64 bit. What command I need to use or how I do that at all ?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need not only *a command* but whole [64-bit MinGW toolchain](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) - a 64bit compiler in the first place. Then the parameters to your gcc invocation should work the same.

Beware that 64bit is not just a matter of compilability. Primitive data types have different sizes, so any code making assumptions without `sizeof` checking is a potential issue. Most prominently, pointer arithmetic.